# Why do some assets give 403 forbidden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dragonfly-gem

I am using ROR, nginx, passenger...

If there is no picture in the DB then my app will serve the 'default_avatar.png'. I noticed I was unable to save new pictures. So, I updated my dragonfly initializer to point at my db server:

```
...
  # I have obscured the host IP for this example. 
  config.url_host = Rails.env.production? ? 'http://IP_OF_HOST' : 'http://localhost:3000'
...
```

Now I can save pictures and view them through my app, but the 'default_avatar.png' does not resolve. Oddly enough, other image assets do seem to come through. Why do I get 403? At first guess I thought it was a permissions error. But then why would it serve the other images?

UPDATE:

I have just noticed a very important clue. When the assets do not work, they have the url:

```
/media/jakbfAGasgAgADSGANJGFDgbnadglnalgbakljbgkjabg/default_avatar.png
```

And when they do work:

```
/assets/avatar.png
```

I should mention that I have 2 app servers and 1 db server. I do not believe it to be a permissions error.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions for default_avatar.png? Maybe they differ from the files you upload (since they are created by the server) and Nginx cannot read them.

Comment: I have updated my question to add more info. I dont think its permissions. As they would have failed before I updated my initializer.

Comment: Are you precompiling your assets?

Comment: The assets are precompiled

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem.

You need to specify the extension of the file when using the html helper provided by `AssetTagHelper` lib.

This will work:
`<%= image_tag('avatar.png') %>`

This won't work:
`<%= image_tag('avatar') %>`

Not easy to debug.